# cut out specific fields from text file

Tags: cut

I have a text file with 9 fields separated by :

```
survey:m1111771::rent:travel:::Morning:
```

How do I pull field 1 and 8 only to a separate file

for example it would look like this,

```
survey:Morning
```

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways:

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1":"$8}' <file>
survey:Morning
```

and as @cas as pointed out, where `OFS` is the "Output Field Separator"

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=: '{print $1,$8}'
survey:Morning
```

Comment: hard-coding a single double-quoted `:` character is OK when you're only printing two fields, but it gets tedious and error-prone very quickly if you want to print more fields.  It's better to set the Output Field Separator (OFS) to `:`.  e.g. `awk -F: -v OFS=: '{print $1,$8}'`.   hard-coding it is also a pain if you ever want to change it (e.g. to a tab or a comma), as you'd then have to manually change every occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Another version using `cut` :

```
cut -d: -f1,8 file > newfile
```